# .NET Core + Angular SPA to Azure

Tags: angular, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have been trying to deploy .net Core solution which has Web APIs and Angular SPA (ClientApp Folder), I have been trying to deploy the same using visual studio code but somehow it is not publishing the application.

I have tried following so far in order to resolve the issue

```
1. ng build --prod
2. ng serve
```

Both of them works properly. and application works in localhost. I have also tried below command
`dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish;` to create publish folder and tried publishing. I have also tried publishing ClientApp folder within dist folder.

**Please note that everything is within one solution only, and i wanted to keep it that way :) **

Comment: What issue are you getting? errors in the Azure Pipeline?

Comment: you must be following some azure doc to help you out. put that here. alternatively, try and put your code in a public repo and link it here. right now, the question is really not clear.

Comment: Yes I have been following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prRBys1h8iw but it does not work and i could not find something which allows me to deploy my API and SPA in same WebApp in Azure...  hope this is bit more clear....

Comment: Are you also using Azure DevOps here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `ng build --prod` command, a build project will be created for you under the  `/dist/project-name/` folder. The content of this folder which include a `index.html` is what you can serve on the web server (**IIS**, **Nginx**, ...). If you want to deploy the backend (.net Core) & client the should be served by a web server. If you just want to test the deploy Angular app you can use `http-server` which is a simple, zero-configuration command-line http server. You can install it by the following command:

```sh
npm install -g http-server
```

After installation and building Angular app open a Terminal/CMD and `CD`to the `/dist/project-name/` where there is `index.html` and serve it by the following command:

```sh
http-server -p [PORT]
```

e.g. if you want to serve it on your `localhost` and port `8080` this is the command:

```sh
http-server -p 8080
```

But, for production mode and deploy on the server you have to choose a web server such as `Nginx` or `IIS` and deply both app on..

For deploying on Azure, after building Angular app these are the general steps:

> 1. Create an Azure App Service on: `Home > App Services`
> 2. Configure your Azure App Service on: `Home > App Services > Web App`
> 3. Disable Application Insights (Optional) option on: `Home > App Services > Web App`
> 4. Review and Create App Service on: `Home > App Services > Web App`, 4th Tab => `Create + Review`
> 5. Configure App Service Deployment Process using Local Git
> 6. Review your Git/Deployment username and Git clone `url`
> 7. Configure an Azure Deployment User
> 8. Verify deployment user and Clone App Service Git `Repo`
> 9. Prepare a Local Deployment Folder and Clone the Azure App Service Git Repo
> 10. Commit and Push Deployment Package to Azure Dev Ops Repository

For details read this helpful article: [Deploy Angular 8+ Application to Azure App Service(PaaS) using Local Git(CD](https://medium.com/@kevinding0218/deploy-angular-8-application-to-azure-app-service-paas-using-local-git-cd-10d32f6f8629)

Comment: Hi I am trying to deploy the app in Azure's App.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer for you. Check it out. let m know if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks, I was already doing above steps which works. however VS code was throwing very generic error. however, i have figured it out that it was because of Budget property in anguar.json file. once i have fixed maximum length.  i could build it properly and then deployment happen without any issue

Comment: Great job dude. ;)